# How to Display a Database data in jtextarea by using time delay?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

```
  int time = 0;
  time++; // set by 1second
  int countdata = 0; // countdata queried by table shows the numbers of table values
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ID,test From Table");
            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while (rs.next()) {

           strBuilder.append(rs.getString(0)).append(" ").append(rs.getString(1));
           strBuilder.append("\n");



            if(time <= countdata){
            // this is my idea but i dont know how to fetch the data each row
             }

           jtextarea.setText(strBuilder.toString());
            }
```

the output is like this:

```
//  time 1 seconds
test1
// time 2 seconds
test2
// time 3 reconds
test3
//until it reach the last data of table
```

please help

i want to fetch data by every 1 second until it reach the last value. the time is fix by 1 second delay. every 1 second shows the row of data.

Comment: so you want to fetch and display results with X amount of time ?

Answer (score 1):

You have two basic choices (there are others, but lets keep it simple...)

Basically, you want to perform the query in some kind of background thread but ensure that the updates to the UI are carried out within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread...

This ensures that while the query is taking place, the UI remains responsive to the user and to won't make it look like your application has crashed...

### You Could...

Use a Swing `Timer` to schedule a call back every `n` milliseconds.  The benefit of this is that it the callback is triggered within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

The drawback is that the callback is triggered within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

The main problem I see is you don't want to be querying the database from the context of the EDT as this will prevent it from performing updates to the UI and remaining responsive to the user while the processing is occurring.

Now you could spawn another `Thread` at this stage, but the problem is, the time it takes to complete the query may be more than the time allocated between updates, meaning that it would be possible for last query to still be running when the next one is triggered.  You also run into issues with having to synchronise updates to the UI manually, while not especially difficult, why would you want to make life more difficult ;)

Take a look at [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details

### You Could...

Use a `SwingWorker`.  This will allow you to perform the query in a background thread while providing you with functionality to send updates back to the Event Dispatching Thread so the UI can be updated properly.

The drawback with this is that the `SwingWorker` doesn't have timer concept of it's own, but, you could simply use `Thread.sleep`.

Now, depending on whether you want regular updates; ie they MUST occur every second, exactly, or delayed updates; ie they must occur every second AFTER the last update will depend on how you use this, but what this means is you gain control.

Basically what this means is, you can ensure that only one query is been executed at a time and control the amount of time before the next one.

Take a look at [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

Comment: thank you sir but can u help me how to fetch data each rows? i updated my post

Comment: I would assume you would need some other identify in table, some kind of sequence value, that would be able increment on each iteration OR simply load the results from table and as iterate over each row, send that result to the UI and wait for 1 second...

Comment: I use the rs.first() and rs.last() method and make a variable integer firstcount and lastcount. use it for querying by where clause column field ID. 

for(int i = firstcount; i < lastcount+1; i++){
//blah blah database statement
// put integer i in where clause statement
"where ID='"+i+"' ";
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
finally it works
thanks a lot Mr. MadProgrammer